# Facebook XFBML Share box: pop up window vs. modal window setting? Modal window never loads

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml, facebook-sharer

I've tried two Facebook Share buttons with the following:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
    FB.init({
             appId  : '123456780',
             status : true, // check login status
             cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
             xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    </script>
        <fb:share-button href="http://example.com" type="box_count"> </fb:share-button>
```

One used a modal window, the other a pop-up window. The only difference was the appId. Is this setting somewhere on https://developers.facebook.com/apps? Which setting determines modal vs. pop-up and how does this setting change things for FB sign-in, like buttons, etc.?

Also, the modal window never loads completely, hence the reason I need to switch it to the pop-up window. If I could get the modal window to load completely, I'd just go with that.

Answer (score 0):

The share button has been deprecated, and I don't think it was ever possible to control the dialog's behavior. Since you're already including the Javascript SDK, you should look into implementing a [feed dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) in place of the share button.

In general, when Facebook is opening a dialog with a popup window, it's because they cannot determine the logged in Facebook user's status. If they need to prompt the user to log in, they will not do so using the iframe (modal) method due to security restrictions.